# Add a property to ng-grid column

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

Using ng-grid, I'd like to add my own tooltip, using a header cell template. To do so I'd like to create a column property called "tooltip" for instance. Tried that and it doesn't show up in the col properties. What do you think about giving us that functionality. Otherwise I create a new template in each case?

See plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lSf4XK?p=preview

Ideally, the gridOptions would contain columnDefs like this:

```
  columnDefs: [
    {field: 'complex.name', displayName: 'Name', headerCellTemplate:'header_template2.html'},
    {field:'complex.active', 
    dimension1: "Testing",
    displayName: 'In Progress', 
    headerCellTemplate:'header_template.html', 
    cellTemplate : 'checkBoxTemplate.html'}]
```

and that `dimension1` property would be accessible in the template like so:

```
<div tooltip="{{col.dimension1}}">{{col.displayName}}</div>
```

Comment: On stack overflow you should always include the source code in the post.  Regarding this particular issue if you have a known work-around you could post that then also link to this post and file a feature request with the ng-grid team.

Comment: I'll update the question. As for the plunkr I ended up working on the original (also probably not a good idea). I opened an issue with the ng-grid team before I asked the question but have since closed it. I'll reopen it and let them close it if they want to. Lazy questioning I admit.

Comment: Cool yeah just figured this probably wouldn't get an answer here as I've seen a couple of grid extension requests here with no response.  This would be a nice built in though too if you think it's clean enough it might be worth posting a pull request... if you drop the link I'd vote for it, would be nice to have for column descriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built a solution - more of a workaround - here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0PMmrw?p=preview

Here's an excerpt. I make `displayName` an object instead of a string:

```
  columnDefs: [
    {field: 'complex.name', displayName: 'Name'},
    {field:'complex.active', 
    cellClass: 'overflow-visible',
    displayName: {name:'In Progress', tooltip:'Testing'}, 
    headerCellTemplate:'header_template.html', 
    cellTemplate : 'checkBoxTemplate.html'}]
```

And then refer to it in the cell template like so:

```
  <div ng-click="col.sort($event)" ng-class="'colt' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText" tooltip="{{col.displayName.tooltip}}">{{col.displayName.name}}</div>
```

**Edit**

The problem with this is that it will throw errors because the implementation of ng-grid expects displayName to be a string (at least in v2.0.7); it calls col.displayName.toLowerCase().

Comment: very clever workaround - it's good to know that objects can be used, not just strings

Comment: The implementation of ng-grid expects displayName to be a string (at least in v2.0.7); it calls col.displayName.toLowerCase().

Comment: Very true. I've edited my solution. Truth is, actually, those errors, plus lagging, and incompatibility with older IE browsers led me to bail on ng-grid altogether. I'm using Smart-Table now which was easy to customize. (https://github.com/morgs32/Smart-Table in case you're interested)

Comment: Hello, I'm using bootstrap 3.0, ui-bootstrap 0.10, nggrid 2.0.11 and your solution don't work, could you check it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use cellClass/headerClass properties in my case i am not using cellClass for my columns so i used cellClass. I wanted attribute "help-id" on my each column header.

In your column definition:

```
{field: 'id.value',       displayName: $scope.CONFIGVLANSlabels.tbl_vlans_id,             enableCellEdit: true,   editableCellTemplate: idEditCellTemplate,         headerCellTemplate: myHeaderCellTemplate,   cellClass:'tbl_vlans_id'}
```

In your header template

```
var myHeaderCellTemplate        = '<div class="ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}" ng-style="{cursor: col.cursor}" ng-class="{ ngSorted: !noSortVisible }">'+
                                    '<div ng-click="col.sort($event)" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText" help-id="{{col.cellClass}}">{{col.displayName}}</div>'+
                                    '<div class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="col.showSortButtonDown()"></div>'+
                                    '<div class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="col.showSortButtonUp()"></div>'+
                                    '<div class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>'+
                                  '</div>'+
                                  '<div ng-show="col.resizable" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>';
```

Hope this will help some one.

Answer (score 1):

(Cannot add a comment to the accepted answer due to rep score, so I'm adding it here)

An easy solution to get around the script errors of the accepted answer, a simple JavaScript object can be created to support the toLowerCase() call using in ng-grid:

```
  function DisplayObject(name, tooltip) {
    // this refers to the new instance
    this.name = name;
    this.tooltip = tooltip;
    // you can also call methods
    this.toLowerCase = function() {
      return this.name.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
```

And then use it like this:

```
columnDefs: [
    {field: 'complex.name', displayName: 'Name'},
    {field:'complex.active', 
    cellClass: 'overflow-visible',
    displayName: new DisplayObject('In Progress','Testing'), 
    headerCellTemplate:'header_template.html', 
    cellTemplate : 'checkBoxTemplate.html'}]
```

ng-grid will then no longer complain about the toLowerCase(), and the name will be added to the ng-grid fieldMap.

Comment: Thank you, this fix some ng-grid console errors that I've on the page load

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 3.0, ui-bootstrap 0.10, nggrid 2.0.11, in order to make it works I define a header column template like the answer template, the difference is to use a tooltip-append-to-body="true" attribute for the tooltip. The cellClass: 'overflow-visible' in the column def is not neccesary.

```
<div class="ngHeaderSortColumn {{col.headerClass}}" ng-style="{'cursor': col.cursor}" ng-class="{ 'ngSorted': !noSortVisible }">
    <div ng-click="col.sort($event)" ng-class="'colt' + col.index" class="ngHeaderText" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip="{{col.displayName.tooltip}}">{{col.displayName.name}}</div>
    <div class="ngSortButtonDown" ng-show="col.showSortButtonDown()"></div>
    <div class="ngSortButtonUp" ng-show="col.showSortButtonUp()"></div>
    <div class="ngSortPriority">{{col.sortPriority}}</div>
    <div ng-class="{ ngPinnedIcon: col.pinned, ngUnPinnedIcon: !col.pinned }" ng-click="togglePin(col)" ng-show="col.pinnable"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="col.resizable" class="ngHeaderGrip" ng-click="col.gripClick($event)" ng-mousedown="col.gripOnMouseDown($event)"></div>
```